# How would I do big math whilst operating withing the kernel?

Tags: c, math, linux-kernel, cryptography

I am making a client for a server that operates in kernel-space and am attempting to write my own protocol for encryption, mostly due to the fact that it seems fun but also because no user-space libraries like openssl work in kernel-space. I am using a uint8_t[64] for my keys, but am really rather unsure how I would impediment mathematical operations such as pow().

is there some pre-built big math library that operates in kernel-space, and if not how would I perform mathematical operations upon them?

Comment: If you can do addition and multiplication, then integer exponentiation is trivial.  Initialize a temporary to the number being raised to a power, then loop over the bits of the exponent, squaring the temporary each time.  It should iterate log(n) times, where n is the exponent.

Comment: @TomKarzes: Integer exponentiation is not really trivial, as the minimum number of multiplications needed is not known, except for very small exponents.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made up clearer- I don't know how to do any mathematical operations on the array, including addition and multiplication. Exponentiation was just an example

Comment: Why don't the user-space libraries work in kernel space? If it's because of dynamic linking, can't you just compile static binaries?

Comment: @EricPostpischil The most commonly used technique, exponentiation by squaring, is trivial and more than adequate for most needs.  It does at most log(n) squarings and multiplications, where n is the exponent. I wasn't suggesting anything more complicated than that.

Comment: @Artemis'sAngel If you want to support extended-precision integer arithmetic, then you need to either use some existing library, or else write your own.  For the former, you can search around the web to see what's there.  For the latter, you'll need to roll up your sleeves, work out the math, and code it.

Comment: The [libtom](https://github.com/libtom) project includes mostly straightforward code that eschews faster but more complex algorithms in favor of simpler, easier to understand, and easier to code/shorter code algorithms. For example, see [libtommath](https://github.com/libtom/libtommath). You may have to adapt it to work in kernel-space.

Comment: Seems nobody in the comments got the tag `crypto` correctly. So, I would suggest to look into _crypto_ subsystem in the Linux kernel. There are plenty of the examples on how to handle keys inside the kernel.